# Converting on click event to a router

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I have the below codes in a old ionic 3, currently I have to migrate to ionic 5. I have googled it, but still find it confusing.

In my Html

```html
(click)="onAllergiesDetailsClicked(medicalAlertGroup , 'Medical Alert')"
```

In my TS file

```js
onAllergiesDetailsClicked(allergiesGroupLists, pageTitle) {
  this.navCtrl.push(AllergiesGroupListPage, { allergiesGroupList: allergiesGroupLists, pageTitle: pageTitle });
}
```

In my ts in AllerhiesGroupList Page

```js
let allergiesGroupList: PatientAllergiesGroup = this.navParams.get('allergiesGroupList');
this.pageTitle = this.navParams.get('pageTitle');
this.patientAllergiesLists = (allergiesGroupList.patientAllertList.sort(this.sortingDate));
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: How do I convert the HTML click to router comman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a service named data:

```
export class dataService {
setvalue:any;
constructor(){}
setDestValue(param){
     this.setvalue = param;
}

getDestValue(){
    return this.setvalue;
}
}
```

Second thing in your page you need to send data from:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {DataService} from 'put service path here';
constructor(private dataService:DataService,private router:Router...)

onAllergiesDetailsClicked(allergiesGroupLists, pageTitle){ 
    this.dataService.setDestValue({ allergiesGroupList: allergiesGroupLists, pageTitle: pageTitle });
    this.router.navigate(["name of page to navigate to as it is named in app-routing"]);
}
```

And in the page its routed to:

```
import {DataService} from 'put service path here';

constructor(private dataService:DataService...){
    let data = this.dataService.getDestValue();
    this.pagetitle = data.pageTitle;
    this.grouplist = data.allergiesGroupList;
}
```

Thats all .

Comment: I follow the example give, when i run the app i got this errorERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AllergiesPage -> AllergiesService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AllergiesPage -> AllergiesService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AllergiesService!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AllergiesPage -> AllergiesService]

Comment: Ok fot the example i did there is no service to be added , but for AllergiesService , they say it should be in providers in app.module.ts